# What are the meanings of those connection limit configurations for Firefox?

Tags: http, firefox, configuration

What are the meaning of those connection limit configurations for Firefox?

network.http.max-connections
network.http.max-connections-per-server
network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-proxy
network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Comment: and you could google it yourself: it's the first hit each.

Comment: stackoverflow is better than google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
network.http.max-connections
```

The maximum number of connections that Firefox will open at the same time.

```
network.http.max-connections-per-server
```

The number of open connections that Firefox opens to a single server.

```
network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-proxy
```

The maximum number of persistent connections to a proxy server.

```
network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server
```

The maximum number of persistent ("keep-alive") connections to a single server

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: Doesnt persistent connection require only one TCP connection?